# jQuery wait for a function to complete before new fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two functions in jQuery that I want to fire in a specific order. The first function is an ajax function which updates a partial view. The other one is supposed to do some styling on the partial view, once the ajax function has completed - this function takes a parameter.

```
ajaxFunction();
stylingFunction(params);
```

I have tried the following:

```
ajaxFunction(function() {
    stylingFunction(params)
});
```

Also, I have tried to use a callback:

```
ajaxFunction(stylingfunction(params));

ajaxFunction(callback)
{
    //Do update
    callback()
}
```

None of these do however work. The styling appears shortly where after it dissapears because the partial view is getting updated. Where am I going wrong here?

Both functions are written in my "parent" view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .done() and .fail() chained to the $.ajax call ...

I created a couple callback functions with psuedo-code inside the successCallback() since you said you only need to run the styling function "sometimes".  You will want to test whatever condition inside that function to determine if you want to run the styling function.  Hope this helps.

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {   //document.ready

    $.ajax({ cache: false,
        url: "/blah/vlah/lah",
        data: { somedata: somedata }
    })
    .done(successCallback)
    .fail(failCallback);

  });

    function successCallback(data) {
        if (someCondition) {
            stylingFunction(params);
        }
    };

    function failCallback(jqXHR, status, error) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(error);
        console.log(status);
    };

})(jQuery);
```

I created another gist which handles ajax event delegation, you may want to review and incorporate anything that seems helpful to your situation.
https://gist.github.com/inceptzero/a753d020648f49da90f8

I also created this gist on github for an ajax request queue which is a bit more elegant and robust.
https://gist.github.com/inceptzero/e64756f9162ca6aeeee5

Comment: thank you for your answer, but its not a feasible solution unfortunately. I don't necessarily have to call the `Stylingfunction` all the time.

Comment: Hence the reason why I am posting my question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery you could `const ajaxFunc = callback => $.ajax({...}).done( data => callback)` Also you could use async/await. You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).